# Addrange on double[,]

Tags: c#

I have a function that returns a double[,]. I need to loop over this and collect the result. I know that it will always return 2 columns only, but I do not know the number of rows the function returns.

What is the best way to collect results?

I tried to use addrange, but this does not seem to be possible on double[,].

In code:

```
public static double[,] downloadtable(double start, double end, string url)
{
    DateTime t1 = DateTime.FromOADate(start);
    DateTime t2 = DateTime.FromOADate(end);
    var datediff = Convert.ToInt32((t2 - t1).TotalDays) + 1;
    var reslist = new List<double[,]>();

    for (int i = 0; i < datediff; i++)
    {
         double[,] temp = somefunction(start+i,url);
         reslist.AddRange(temp);
    }
}
```

Whats the best way to collect results of unknown lenght and then return a double[,] again?

**Update** - this was pretty dumn question, anyways here the working solution. In case somebody can think of sth better please let me know.

```
        public static double[,] downloadtable(double start, double end, string url)
           {
        DateTime t1 = DateTime.FromOADate(start);
        DateTime t2 = DateTime.FromOADate(end);
        var datediff = Convert.ToInt32((t2 - t1).TotalDays) + 1;
        var reslist = new List<double[,]>();

        Parallel.For(0, datediff, i =>
        {
            var temp = downloadone(start + i, url);
            reslist.Add(temp);
        });

        var cnt = reslist.Count;
        var cnt2 = new int[cnt];

        for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
        {
            cnt2[i]= reslist[i].GetLength(0);
        }

        var res = new double[cnt2.Sum(), 2];
        var acc = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < cnt; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < cnt2[j]; i++)
            {
                res[acc, 0] = reslist[j][i, 0];
                res[acc, 1] = reslist[j][i, 1];
                acc++;
            }
        }
        return res;

    }
```

Comment: What is this `AddRange` call supposed to do? Based on the types involved `Add` would work.

Comment: If it will always have 2 columns, why not use `List<T>` with `T` as a custom class, struct, or `Tuple<double,double>`?

Comment: I have used addrange before, but I guess that was when I added a list to a list, somehow I thought of double[,] like a list but I guess it is not

Comment: `double[,]` is fixed size array. use the `.GetLength(0)` and `.GetLengh(1)` functions to get the rows and columns.